# Forgot password not send any email magento2-gmailsmtpapp.

Tags: magento-2.1, email, password, magento-2.1.7, send-mail

I want the system automatically send email to the user (who forgot password and provide the email). I am using Magento 2.1.7.

I have installed https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp on my Magento application.

After config my gmail account (enable imap and less secure app) I am able to send test email.

But when I provide email and click reset password, no email send to my account.

How can I config Magento admin to be able to send reset password email to the user(when they forgot password)? I am newbie in magento.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't sent?  (ie are they in your junk?)  Why have you enabled imap?  If I were you and I had paid for an extension, my first port of call would be the developers.

Comment: Also, if you have a website, you have a domain, so you can setup your own email...  Which is a lot more complicated that answering your question.